# How to structure sales of reports

Tags: custom-post-types, e-commerce, membership

I'm starting a new project where the business model is that they sell reports and, also, unlimited access to reports for a recurring fee.

I'm having trouble thinking of how to implement this. I'm familiar with membership models, and ecommerce models, but this in-between feels complicated.

To be more specific, it works as follows. If you buy a single report, you go to the payment gateway and get your report right away. If you pay for a subscription, you get as many reports as you want, until the subscription expires.

To make it a little more complicated, these reports are generated dynamically. I'm thinking I'll use a CPT for this, and everytime a person purchases a report, it will store the ID of the report-subject and a date, and then it will generate the report based on that info.

How do you sell things (the reports) that will only be created once they are purchased? How do you differentiate it when there is a membership?

There are also 2 types of users asking for reports: employees and employers. So if I sell one of them a membership, would their type turn into membership employee and membership employer?

On the other hand, the payment gateway I'm required to use has implementations for WooCommerce and WP eCommerce, so I'm leaning towards something that will take advantage of that. It's not the only option I would consider tho, I could integrate the payment gateway myself.

Any suggestions on how to organize this, or even keywords for me to google will be welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The closest in my experience was probably working with customizable digital WooComerce products. Users edited the product on site and then purchased the customized version.

From technical point of view my implementation did the following:

1. Stored ongoing (before purchase) customizations in user meta
2. On order paid detached customizations from user and transferred them to order meta

That way users retained access for exact state they paid for and file could be generated again for them on demand from order page.

Where it started to bog down was allowing users to customize and purchase *multiple versions of same product in one order*. At that point requirements just shoot out of what was reasonable scope under circumstances.